# No video in VBA-M in Wine

Tags: wine, video

So I’ve been trying to get VBA-M running on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) 32x
via Wine and it's almost working. The only problem I'm having now is a generic Sound only (no video) output issues. Thanks for any and all help with this frustrating problem. 
P.S It seems like there'd be documentation on this problem. But all of my searches for anything related have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA-M I fixed the no video problem by going into the Options->Video->Render API->and switched it to OpenGL.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Hadi Is This Better?

Comment: Accept this as an answer if you can.  We don't edit titles to say "FIXED", we select an answer and mark it as such.

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry, it made we wait a couple of days to do so.